# Reverse proxy in ASP.NET Web API 2 Controller?

Tags: c#, proxy, asp.net-web-api2, handler

> I'm trying to set a reverse proxy in my Web-Api controller, so that I
>   can filter the requests vía URI and send them to their respective
>   destinataries.

So far I have a reverse proxy in Node.js + Express as following, that I'm trying to migrate to the WebApi controller:

```
var serverOne = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/TRAC/wms?';
var serverTwo = 'https://iden.com/ogc/wms?';
var serverThree = 'https://inspi.com/services/CP/wfs';

app.all('/geoserver', function (req, res) {
  apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: serverOne});
});

app.all('/idena', function (req, res) {
  apiProxy.web(req, res, {
    changeOrigin: true,
    target: serverTwo
    });
});

app.all('/inspire', function (req, res) {
  apiProxy.web(req, res, {
    changeOrigin: true,
    target: serverThree
    });
});
```

So this is basically what I'm trying to achieve:

- If I get a `localhost:65000/geoserver` request, resend it to `serverOne`
- If I get a `localhost:65000/idena` request, resend it to `serverTwo`
- If I get a `localhost:65000/inspire` request, resend it to `serverThree`

I have been researching different methods as using a Handler or installing third part components, but I'm not sure that these are correct approaches.

> Which techniques or technologies should I use to set a reverse
>   proxy on my controller in ASP.NET Web API 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible directly in the WebAPI controller, but this can easily be done adding an ASP.NET handler to the project.

[image]

And then creating the reverse proxy as mentioned [here](https://auth0.com/blog/building-a-reverse-proxy-in-dot-net-core/)